# How to make a "top queries" page

Tags: python, sql, multithreading

A website I am making revolves around a search utility, and a want to have something on the homepage that lists the top 10 (or something) most searched queries of the day.

What would be the easiest / most efficient way of doing this?

Should I use a sql database, or just a text file containing the top 10 queries and a cronjob erasing the data every day?

Also, how would I avoid the problem of two users searching for something at the same and it only recording one of them, i.e multithreading?

The back-end of the site is all written in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the queries in a table, with one row per distinct query, and a column to count. Insert if the query doesn't exist already, or otherwise increment the query row counter.

Put a cron job together than empties the table at 12 midnight. Use transactions to prevent two different requests from colliding.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a database backend, any python framework and RDBMS combination will be able to handle the concurrency, that should be the least of your problems.

Just keep logging the full query search string (combination of words?) to a table and at the end of the day, use a simple aggregation query to produce the result.

A simple table like this will do (using MySQL as an example)

```
query: id autonumber, search_time datetime, search_string varchar
```

You can query it on the fly for the top 10

```
select date(search_time), search_string, count(*) times_searched
from query
group by date(search_time), search_string
order by 3 desc
limit 0,10;
```

Or you can throw the query into a CRON job to produce a static file (per date) for performance reasons, since the list of 10 items will never change.

For auditing, you can keep the table entries, or if not required, just empty data for the previous day once the static top-10 for yesterday has been produced.